# Python: scipy.optimize.minimize fails with "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence." when calling on a function with x and y args

Tags: python, scipy, minimize

As stated in title, scipy.optimize.minimize fails with "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence." when calling minimize.

I'm applying scipy.optimize.minimize to a function that uses the variables coef (coefficients that I'm optimizing) and xData and yData (data variables).

I'll provide an example code below. I am aware through searching on how to use minimize that the error stems from the function being minimized returning an array when it should return a scalar. I'm not sure *why* it is returning an array, though.

Importantly, scipy.optimize.least_squares works and it seems to share the same syntax as scipy.optimize.minimize. scipy.optimize.fmin does not work either and it's included as well - it's the same as minimize with the Nelder-Mead method, which I'm calling.

Here is some generalized example code that has the error on Python 3:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import least_squares
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from scipy.optimize import fmin
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xData = np.linspace(50,94,334);
yData = (xData-75)**2 + (np.random.random((334,))-.5)*600;

fun = lambda coef, x : coef[0] + coef[1]*x + coef[2]*x**2 ; #create a "lambda" function whatever that is that has a tuple for the polynomial coefficients in it
#function is y = coef0 + coef1*x + coef2*x^2 where y is lambda

funError = lambda coef, x, y: fun(coef,x) - y; #create a "lambda" function for the error between the real data y and the fit data y
#function is yError = y(coef,x) - yReal where yError is the lambda now
#expanded fully: yError = coef0 + coef1*x + coef2*x^2 - yReal

coef_init = (5,10,15); #initial coefficient guess
#coef0 is const (order 0)
#coef1 is order 1 coef
#coef2 is order 2 coef

coef = least_squares(funError,coef_init, args=(xData,yData) ); #calculate the polynomial coefficients to fit the data
yFit_lq = fun(coef.x,xData); #calc the guessed values 
plt.figure();
plt.scatter( xData , yData , 20 , "r" );
plt.scatter( xData , yFit_lq , 20 );
plt.title("Least Squares");
plt.show();

coef = minimize(funError,coef_init, args=(xData,yData),method="Nelder-Mead" ); #calculate the polynomial coefficients to fit the data
yFit_min = fun(coef.x,xData); #calc the guessed values 
plt.figure();
plt.scatter( xData , yData , 20 , "r" );
plt.scatter( xData , yFit_min , 20 );
plt.title("Minimize with Nelder-Mead");
plt.show();

coef = fmin(funError,coef_init, args=(xData,yData) ); #calculate the polynomial coefficients to fit the data
yFit_fmin = fun(coef.x,xData); #calc the guessed values 
plt.figure();
plt.scatter( xData , yData , 20 , "r" );
plt.scatter( xData , yFit_fmin , 20 );
plt.title("fmin, equiv to min. w/ neldy");
plt.show();
```

I call least_squares, minimize, and fmin the same way and their pages just ask for args=(). I'm not sure what is going wrong in calling minimize and fmin that the "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence." error occurs while least_squares is perfectly happy with the formatting.

I would also prefer to avoid excess function defs - the clean and simple lambda function should be able to handle this simple case.

Comment: "I'm not sure *why* it is returning an array, though." - I'm not sure why you're surprised it's returning an array. You pass a bunch of arrays into your function, do a bunch of broadcasted math, and get an array as a result.

Comment: Were you expecting `x` and `y` *not* to be arrays for some reason?

Comment: What does `funError(coef_init, xData, yData)` produce?  That's how `minimize` will call your function, given these `args`.

Comment: These comments are great. Passing data vectors to a fitting function is essential - and passing them through args=() seems to be the only way. I'm well aware it looks like an array in and array out, but there must be another way to make it work for fmin - it works for least_squares as it would ideally (least_squares uses the data vectors to fill perform its optimization on the model function's coefficients). I'm hoping someone that has experience implementing an x/y fit with fmin or minimize can suggest ways to get them to play ball as least_squares does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`least_squares` and `minimize` have different requirements for the objective function.

[`least_squares`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html) expects your function to return a vector.  The docstring describes this vector as the "vector of residuals".  `least_squares` takes this vector and sums the squares of the elements to form the *actual* objective function that is minimized.

[`minimize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) expects your objective function to return a *scalar*.  It tries to find the vector input that minimizes the scalar output of your function.

You can solve the least squares optimization problem with `minimize` by modifying your existing function so that it computes and returns the sum of the squared residuals:

```
def funError(coef, x, y):
    residuals = fun(coef,x) - y
    objective = (residuals**2).sum()
    return objective
```

But then that function is not set up to use with `least_squares`.  So instead, you could use two functions:

```
def funError(coef, x, y):
    residuals = fun(coef,x) - y
    return residuals

def funErrorSSR(coef, x, y):
    residuals = funError(coef, x, y)
    objective = (residuals**2).sum()
    return objective
```

Use `funError` with `least_squares`, and `funErrorSSR` with `minimize` (or `fmin`).